# unable to convert excel file to pdf using office.interop.excel on my local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, com

I need to export excel file to pdf using microsoft.office.interop.excel, the program runs well on my IIS express environement but when i have deployed it on my local IIS, i found a lot of exceptions caused by the using of COM objects.

The error :

```
 
    System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID  {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error : 80070005 Access denied. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

Can you please show me the good IIS settings that it fix my problem ? i have followed the floowing link, but i'm still blocked : https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1129/37/access-denied-exception-from-hresult-0x80070005-e_accessdenied

If the using of microsoft.office.interop.excel was not the good choice, can you recommend me an open source or free library that it can convert excel to pdf without limitation.

Comment: "found a lot of exceptions" or "The error" Well, which is it? one error or many errors? If many show some detail.

Comment: Did you have Office installed on the IIS server?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

Comment: Yes i have office excel on my local post on which i have run application using iis express and iis local. my application run well on my iis express but it crashes on my local IIS (iis installed on my machine to simulate the production environment).

Comment: not sure about the PDF part of it, but NPOI works well for the excel side of things.  COM is going to be a little slow and clunky... especially if a lot of users are hitting the code that calls it.